# Why does this span tag not use the CSS class I have specified?

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS problem with this custom theme on which I am working: http://www.asper-eritrea.com/

At the beginning of the website (under the header slideshow) there are the following text lines:

```
ASPER
Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo
COORDINAMENTO ERITREA DEMOCRATICA
```

These line are shown by the following HTML:

```
<section id="presentazione">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!--<h1 class="text-center"><small>Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</small></h1>-->
            <!--<h1 class="text-center title">Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</h1>-->
            <h1 class="text-center title">ASPER</h1>
            <h1 class="text-center leadTitle">Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</h1> <!--<h1 class="text-center leadTitle">Association in Defense of the Human Rights of the Eritrean People</h1>-->
            <span class="text-center leadTitle"><a href="http://eritreademocratica.wordpress.com/" target="_blank">COORDINAMENTO ERITREA DEMOCRATICA</a></span>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</section><!-- /section presentazione -->
```

And this is the CSS code related to the used class:

```
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.leadTitle {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

I have also set these classes on the third line (`COORDINAMENTO ERITREA DEMOCRATICA`), but it seems it doesn't see it, and the text is not at center.

What am I missing?

Comment: Because `<h1>` is a [block level element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) while `<span>` is an [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elemente). You will be good if you use a `<div>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<span>` is inline element and property `margin, text-align` etc. not work. You must change tag to `<div>` with class leadTitle or add in your css file this row

```
span.leadTitle{display:block;}
```

Comment: or `display:inline-block` if you want it to display inline but with block-level abilities.

Answer (score 2):

the span is an inline element.

Two ways:

1. Make the span to a div
2. give the outer div the class text-center

http://jsfiddle.net/s7729epu/

```
<section id="presentazione">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
            <h1 class="title">ASPER</h1>
            <h1 class="leadTitle">Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</h1> 
            <span class="leadTitle"><a href="http://eritreademocratica.wordpress.com/" target="_blank">COORDINAMENTO ERITREA DEMOCRATICA</a></span>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</section><!-- /section presentazione -->
```

Answer (score 0):

As has already been stated, a `<span>` is `display: inline` by default and `text-align` will have no affect on an inline element.

Instead of using a `<span>`, why not use a more suitable element such as `<h3>`. Heading elements also happen to be `display: block` by default, so that also fixes your issue. Spans or divs are semantically meaningless, whereas `<h1>` - `<h2>` - `<h3>` indicate a heading and sub-headings, which these seem to be.

HTML / CSS - Note `<h1><h2><h3>`

```css
.text-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.leadTitle {
    font-size: 26px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.4;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="presentazione">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <!--<h1 class="text-center"><small>Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</small></h1>-->
            <!--<h1 class="text-center title">Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</h1>-->
            <h1 class="text-center title">ASPER</h1>
            <h2 class="text-center leadTitle">Associazione per la Tutela dei Diritti Umani del Popolo Eritreo</h2> <!--<h1 class="text-center leadTitle">Association in Defense of the Human Rights of the Eritrean People</h1>-->
            <h3 class="text-center leadTitle"><a href="http://eritreademocratica.wordpress.com/" target="_blank">COORDINAMENTO ERITREA DEMOCRATICA</a></h3>
        </div><!-- /.col-sm-12 -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</section><!-- /section presentazione -->
```